# Disable state maintain

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a gridview and it will maintain checkboxes state while paging in gridview.why the checkboxes will still maintain when i refresh the page?how to disable the checkboxes state maintain after i refresh the page or submit data to database?

```
 private void savechkdvls()
{
    ArrayList usercontent = new ArrayList();
    int index = -1;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GrdRole.Rows)
    {
        index = Convert.ToInt32(GrdRole.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value);
        bool result = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked;
        if (Session["chkditems"] != null)
            usercontent = (ArrayList)Session["chkditems"];
        if (result)
        {
            if (!usercontent.Contains(index))
                usercontent.Add(index);
        }
        else
            usercontent.Remove(index);
    }
    if (usercontent != null && usercontent.Count > 0)
        Session["chkditems"] = usercontent;
}
private void chkdvaluesp()
{
    ArrayList usercontent = (ArrayList)Session["chkditems"];
    if (usercontent != null && usercontent.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GrdRole.Rows)
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(GrdRole.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value);
            if (usercontent.Contains(index))
            {
                CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect");
                myCheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        filldropdown();
        Bind();
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you go to the next page, the checkboxes have the same values as the previous page?

Comment: now my problem is after i refresh the page,the checkbox i tick previously still maintain,i only want to maintain the checkbox while i paging the gridview.any idea how to clear/disable the viewstate?

Comment: the command is simple but I am not sure the way you chose is best practice: 

`Viewstate["name of control"] = null;`

Answer (score -1):

You're able to use

```
ViewState.Clear();
Response.Redirect("~/PageXXX.aspx");
```

to clear the ViewState

Comment: That way you're clearing a Session variable with key "ViewState". The command to clear the ViewState is: `ViewState.Clear()`